# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths for a class that references itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.2

I get the error `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Company_Company_ParentId' on table 'Company' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.` when trying to update a database that contains a class that references itself.

Class that generates the problem:

```
    public class Company
    {
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Company Parent { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

My dbcontext looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ArtGalleries.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ArtGalleries.Data
{
    public class ArtGalleriesContext:DbContext
    {
        public ArtGalleriesContext(DbContextOptions<ArtGalleriesContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ArtItem> ArtItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
        public Company Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
        public Location Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }






        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserLocation>()
                .HasKey(u => new {u.UserId, u.LocationId});
            //modelBuilder.Entity().
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            //    .HasOne(c => c.Company)
            //    .WithOne(pc => pc.Company)
            //    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.ParentId);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=GalleriesDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:the commented text is my attepmt to fix this issue, yet it's fruitless, since i'm getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For self reference in EF Core , you should set the `ParentId` as Nullable and use [ForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotations) to configure which property should be used as the foreign key property for a given relationship like below :

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Company Parent { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId ")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I assume that `int?` is the way you set it as Nullable. Why go through the trouble of setting the foreign key for country as well? Shouldn't EF core do that by itself?Also, is the order in which i declare my props relevant?

Comment: After doing the edits you suggested, i ran into the issue `Cannot find the object "Company" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`. Is this a related issue?

Comment: Where did this error appear? Check if `public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }` is in  your DbContext .

Comment: Apparently, it's not. I declared them like this >.< ```public Company Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
        public Location Locations { get; set; }``` Thanks a lot for the quick response. Problem is, i ran into the same issue for `ArtItems`, and this one is declared in the DBContext. I'll open a new question for this.